# Akka FSM timeout notification

Tags: akka, akka-fsm

I am developing a game where the game logic / state itself is managed by an Akka FSM actor. One of my states is `WaitingForAnswer` and the business logic related to this state is that a player (also an actor) *must* answer within 20 seconds, otherwise he/she loses a point. So I defined the state like this:

```
when(WaitingForAnswer, 20 seconds) {
    // event handling logic here
}
```

So far so good. Now what I want to do is to have some kind of reminder - after half of the state timeout has elapsed (after 10 seconds), I want to send a *reminder* to the player, that he has to answer soon.

My ideas:

1. Using `setTimer(name, msg, interval, repeat)` when entering the `WaitingForAnswer` state by setting the `interval` to 10 seconds. This way my FSM actor will get a *reminder*, reminding him of reminding the player actor. As you can see this is a bit ... well not cool.
2. Use the scheduler and once my FSM actor enters the `WaitingForAnswer` state, schedule a message for 10 seconds in the future with the player actor as a recipient. Of course in this case I would have to make sure that I cancel the scheduled message when the player actor responds in time.

Is there any other more natural way to achieve this? Some kind of hook? Some way to use `setTimer` with a different recipient?

Answer (score 1):

The way you explained your problem, it seems that your state *WaitingForAnswer* is actually 2 different states that behave quite similarly. You could define the state timeout to 10 seconds, if the player answers, logic applies, otherwise, you do a state transition to *WaitingForAnswerAfterReminder* with again 10 seconds state timeout which is handled by the same business logic as the previous state.

To me it looks that you try to model two states within *WaitingForAnswer*: before and after the reminder.

Comment: Thanks, Josep. I actually reviewed your presentation about Game Dev with Akka :) Anyway, I ended up implementing the reminder on client side as the requirement changed slightly but in general I like your idea!

Comment: Glad you liked it!